# how to call a test script from another test script?

Tags: rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

For example : consider the log in function .It is requried for all the test cases .I want to call  the log in test script from my another test scriptooking  say making a b ?Iam using capybara and rspec for automation .

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to write a helper method in login_helper for example, and then call the method from the tests.

Another possibility would be to create a parent class for the test classes that need the log in function and then put it in the before(:each) hook.